# Unable to install Windows Deployment Services

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

So, I got a copy of Windows 2012 R2 Essentials for a home server. And I'm trying to get all the features I want working. The most significant non-working feature right now is "Client Restore Service". Going through the Dashboard GUI, I get:

> Client Restore Service installation did not succeed
>   Windows Deployment Services role installation did not succeed. Exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.PowerShell.ExecutionErrorException was thrown.

Which is less than helpful. So I try adding WDS to the server through the "Add roles and features" GUI. And through the PowerShell cmdlet, both of which give me errors of:

> The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

This being regardless of options I use for installation. I try without using the -source option. And with using the -source option and the USB stick that I installed from. And with the original ISO mounted as a virtual drive on the server. And having copied the install.wim onto the hard drive and using that. The commandline I used last, incidentally is:

> enable-windowsoptionalfeature -online -all -featurename Microsoft-Windows-Deploymment-Services-Deployment-Server -source d:\install.wim

Used variations on the -source parameter previously, all with the same error. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ran chkdsk on my server, then tried re-running the PowerShell command

```
enable-windowsoptionalfeature -online -all -featurename Microsoft-Windows-Deployment-Services-Deployment-Server -source d:\install.wim
```

Gave a different error:

> The component store has been corrupted.

Search online gave the following two command to resolve it:

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

After that, running the first command again succeeded. Client Restore Service now works again.